# Steam выдаёт ошибку "Ошибка записи на диск". Дистрибутив - Debian

Tags: linux, debian, steam

Есть диск - /dev/sda1. Система установлена на /dev/nvme0n1p1 (как и Steam). Я хочу установить игру (Team Fortress 2) на диск /dev/sda1. Но в процессе скачивания, минут через 5-10 пишет "Ошибка записи на диск".

Comment: в `sudo dmesg` должны быть дальнейшие подробности

Comment: Ээээ, ты нам рассказываешь про блочные устройтва? Мы точно говорим про Стим и установку игр? Стим с папками и файлами работает. При чём тут винт и ссд? У тебя прав на каталоги-то хватает?